# Taylor's Series

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

In the definition of Taylor's Series we say "If a function $f$ defined on $[a , a+h]$ is such that all the derivatives up to $(n-1)$-th order are continuous in $[a,a+h]$..."

Why are we taking up to $(n-1)$-th order? Why not up to $n$-th order?

Comment: If $f$ is continuously differentiable $n - 1$ times, Taylor's theorem guarantees the existence of a degree $n$ polynomial approximation. You could also say that if $f$ is continuously differentiable $n$ times, then there is a degree $n + 1$ polynomial approximation.

Comment: I've edited your question. Hope it still expresses what you meant.